# Argument dimensions are incompatible on matplotlib line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to shade the area between two line chart but getting the following error

> 'argument dimensions are incompatible'

I have tried looking at similar questions but cannot seem to get a solution that works in my case.

```
df['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df = df[df['Date'] != 2015]
df_min = df[df['Element'] =='TMIN'].groupby('Date').aggregate({'Data_Value':np.average})
df_max = df[df['Element'] == 'TMAX'].groupby('Date').aggregate({'Data_Value':np.average})
n = np.array(len(df_min))
x = np.linspace(0,n,n,endpoint=True)
plt.plot(df_max, '-o',df_min,'-o')
plt.fill_between(x,df_min,df_max, color='grey',alpha='0.5')
plt.show()
```

Link to the database I am referring to : [Database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wZwT-Y55JnGYhiGwL4A97UaQOGy-lGsS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you check whether the shapes of `x`, `df_min`, and `df_max` are identical?

Comment: @cheersmate df_min & df_max = (10,1), x is (10,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in your code:

- Your x was basically an integer which has a length 0 whereas you needed to pass an array of values which corresponded to the x-scale range (years in your case) over which you want to fill.
- Your `df_min` and `df_max` were DataFrames whereas what you should have passed are the y-values corresponding to `df_min` and `df_max`. These can be accessed using `df_min.values` and `df_max.values`. However, this is an array or arrays. You need to then `flatten` it to get a 1d array in order to use `fill_between`.

Following is one solution:

```
x = df_max.index.values

plt.plot(df_max, '-o',df_min,'-o')
plt.fill_between(x,df_min.values.flatten(),df_max.values.flatten(), color='grey',alpha='0.5')
```

[image]